# SearchApiQuery - possible to remove a filter?

Tags: 7, search

The [query parameter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21search_api%21includes%21query.inc/class/SearchApiQueryFilter/7) that is passed to `search_api_query_alter` has `SearchApiQueryFilter` member. It contains a protected array of filter elements. I can add to this by calling the `createFilter()` and `filter()` methods, but it does not appear that there is a way to remove a filter through the API. 
Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but be careful: it is very tricky! Ideally, it should be special method in the SearchApiQuery class itself, or method in class-wrapper, which will be used everywhere in code...

My solution based on ability to access private members of classes, passed to __constructor function:

```
class SearchApiQueryFilterAlter extends SearchApiQuery
{
    public $altered_query;
    function __construct(SearchApiIndex $index, array $options = array())
    {
        if (isset($options['original_query']) AND isset($options['filter_alter'])) {
            $options['original_query']->filter = $options['filter_alter'];
            $this->altered_query = $options['original_query'];
        } else {
            parent::__construct($index, $options);
        }
    }
}
```

Property $altered_query will contain original query with modified filters.

Usage example:

```
function product_list_search_api_ranges_minmax_alter($variables, $order)
{
    /** @var SearchApiQuery $query */
    $query = $variables['query'];
    $filters = $query->getFilter();
    $new_filters = $query->createFilter();
    foreach($filters->getFilters() as $filter){
       if(!$filter->hasTag('facet:field_product:commerce_price:amount_decimal')){
            $new_filters->filter($filter);
        }
    }
    $options = array(
        'original_query' => $query,
        'filter_alter' => $new_filters
    );
    $filter_alter = new \Drupal\product_list\SearchApiQueryFilterAlter(new SearchApiIndex(), $options);
    $variables['query'] = $filter_alter->altered_query;
}
```

In this example all filters has been copied to the $new_filters, except one with special tag. Then, we pass original query and new filters to class constructor through $variables. And empty SearchApiIndex, which is nesesary. Finally, in $filter_alter->altered_query we have the query with deleted filter condition.